# Opencv warning000.211

Tags: python, opencv, visual-studio-code, ocr

I've been messing around with cv2 and pytesseract last few days and everything was going well until about an hour ago when I kept getting this error

> "[ WARN:0@0.211] global D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgcodecs\src\loadsave.cpp (239) cv::findDecoder imread_('hello.png'): can't open/read file: check file path/integrity"

I've tried uninstalling opencv but nothing tried declaring a variable
with the path to the image then call that through imread() but still
nothing. I'm losing my marbles here man

```
import cv2
import pytesseract as tess
tess.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Users\blkcap\AppData\Local\Programs\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract'
import PIL as Image




img = cv2.imread('hello.png')
text = tess.image_to_string(img)

cv2.resize(img, (800,500))
cv2.imshow('results', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

I have my image in vscode in same working folder so that's why it's being called as shown above

Comment: Which cv2 version are you using?

Comment: 4.5.5 opencv-python

Comment: Can you just check if you are really in the correct directory? Maybe with os.getcwd() just before the reading of the file.

Answer (score 1):

Okay first and foremost thank you both. I figured it out just went into the path where my python.exe was and did the following python39\python.exe **-m pip install opencv-python**

Comment: you can accept this answer to mark the question as resolved.

Answer (score 0):

i faced the same issue :

```
"Pictures\screen1.jpg" 
[ WARN:0@447.011] global D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-pythonA\opencv\modules\imgcodecs\src\loadsave.cpp (239) cv::findDecoder imread_('Pictures\screen1.jpg'): can't open/read file: check file path/integrity
```

in my case it got solved by changing the format to "Pictures\screen1.jpeg"

Answer (score -1):

Try `img = cv2.imread(r'hello.png')` and see if it helps.

[image]

Comment: same error. when I try running pip install opencv2 it gieves me ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement opencv (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for opencv

Comment: @JACKERHAIDAN. I install opencv-python.

Comment: this answer does nothing. for the string `"hello.png"` it makes no difference whether it's a raw string or not. the value is the same.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz. That's because OP's code threw kind of `no supported image` error when i try to reproduce the question and adding `r` solved the question, then I got script executed fine. so i post and think it may be helpful. i don't realized that it's wrong module and glad my comment helped solve the question.

Comment: adding `r` can't have changed the behavior of this code. if the behavior changed, something else did that, and you didn't give that as an answer. you claim that turning the string into a raw string did that when it could not possibly have. whether you see it or not doesn't matter to me. I'll leave this here so people can make up their own minds.